# How to set npm config set proxy on npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi I'm trying to set a proxy every time I run a specific project with my `npm run dev` command.

I have something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv setting up my environment variables but I'm also looking to automating setting my

`npm config set proxy http://proxy.example.com:1337`
`npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.example.com:1337`

Does anyone have any solutions for this?

**Note** That I only want this for my development and note production.

Answer (score 3):

For setting proxy and other configuration for npm just type the following command in the console

**npm config edit**

This command will open the **.npmrc** file, in that file set the `proxy`, `https-proxy` and other setting related **npm**

hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

`npm config set proxy http://proxy.example.com:1337` will set the proxy for downloading the packages from npm repo.

when you run `npm run dev`, what is running is your app which is invoked by npm on node.js on your OS, so you need to set a proxy for your app or your OS.

**System level proxy**

Linux

https://askubuntu.com/questions/583797/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-terminal

Windows:

```
set http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
set https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
set ftp_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
// unset
set http_proxy=
set https_proxy=
set ftp_proxy=
```

**App level**

I can't do anything about that.

**Webpack dev server**

I believe this is what you need, if you are using webpack dev server.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/examples/general/proxy-simple/webpack.config.js